# Php search replacer

Tags: php, string

I have a search String: $str (Something like "test"), a wrap string: $wrap (Something like "|") and a text string: $text (Something like "This is a test Text").

$str is 1 Time in $text. What i want now is a function that will wrap $str with the wrap defined in $wrap and output the modified text (even if $str is more than one time in $text).

But it shall not output the whole text but just 1-2 of the words before $str and then 1-2 of the words after $str and "..." (Only if it isn`t the first or last word). Also it should be case insensitive.

Example:

```
$str = "Text"
$wrap = "<span>|</span>"
$text = "This is a really long Text where the word Text appears about 3 times Text"
```

Output would be:

```
"...long <span>Text</span> where...word <span>Text</span> appears...times  <span>Text</span>"
```

My Code (Obviusly doesnt works):

```
$tempar = preg_split("/$str/i", $text);

        if (count($tempar) <= 2) {
            $result = "... ".substr($tempar[0], -7).$wrap.substr($tempar[1], 7)." ...";
        } else {
            $amount = substr_count($text, $str);

            for ($i = 0; $i < $amount; $i++) {
                $result = $result.".. ".substr($tempar[$i], -7).$wrap.substr($tempar[$i+1], 0, 7)." ..";
            }

        }
```

If you have a tipp or a solution dont hesitate to let me know.

Comment: why not `$temp = str_replace('|', $str, $wrap); echo str_replace($str, $temp, $text);` ?

Comment: @splash58 that would work but then the thing with the word before and after and with "..." wont work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have taken your approach and made it more flexible. If `$str` or `$wrap` changes you could have escaping issues within the regex pattern so I have used [preg_quote](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-quote.php).

Note that I added `$placeholder` to make it clearer, but you can use `$placeholder = "|"` if you don't like `[placeholder]`.

```
function wrapInString($str, $text, $element = 'span') {
    $placeholder = "[placeholder]"; // The string that will be replaced by $str
    $wrap = "<{$element}>{$placeholder}</{$element}>"; // Dynamic string that can handle more than just span
    $strExp = preg_quote($str, '/');

    $matches = [];
    $matchCount = preg_match_all("/(\w+\s+)?(\w+\s+)?({$strExp})(\s+\w+)?(\s+\w+)?/i", $text, $matches);

    $response = '';
    for ($i = 0; $i < $matchCount; $i++) {
        if (strlen($matches[1][$i])) {
            $response .= '...';
        }
        if (strlen($matches[2][$i])) {
            $response .= $matches[2][$i];
        }
        $response .= str_replace($placeholder, $matches[3][$i], $wrap);
        if (strlen($matches[4][$i])) {
            $response .= $matches[4][$i];
        }
        if (strlen($matches[5][$i]) && $i == $matchCount - 1) {
            $response .= '...';
        }
    }
    return $response;
}

$text = "text This is a really long Text where the word Text appears about 3 times Text";
string(107) "<span>text</span> This...long <span>text</span> where...<span>text</span> appears...times <span>text</span>"
```

---

To make the replacement case insensitive you can use the `i` regex option.

Comment: Thanks that works great, but do you have an idea how to do the thing:"But it shall not output the whole text but just 1-2 of the words before $str and then 1-2 of the words after $str and "..." (Only if it isn`t the first or last word)."

Comment: And how do you make this caseinsensitive? Example: If $str is "Text" not only every "Text" will be wrapped but every "text" or "TeXt" ... too.

Comment: I've updated the question to make it case insensitive.

Comment: I've just updated the answer again. This time I fixed it so that the replacement case will match the initial case, e.g. `Text` will be replaced with `<span>Text</span>` and `text` will be replaced with `<span>text</span>`.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correct, just a little bit of implode and explode magic needed

```
$text = "This is a really long Text where the word Text appears about 3 times Text";
$arr = explode("Text", $text);
print_r(implode('&lt;span&gt;Text&lt;/span&gt;', $arr));
```

If you specifically need to render the span tags using HTML, just write it that way

```
$arr = explode("Text", $text);
print_r(implode('<span>Text</span>', $arr));
```

Comment: Thanks, but what if the Text contains "test" in lowercase but $str is uppercase("Test")?

Comment: Just replace the required variables in the explode and implode functions. Assign variable names if required `$arr = explode($findVar, $text)` and `implode($replaceText, $arr)`

Answer (score 0):

Use patern below to get  your word and 1-2 words before and after

```
/((\w+\s+){1,2}|^)text((\s+\w+){1,2}|$)/i
```

[**demo**](https://regex101.com/r/I9xKz6/1)

In PHP code it can be:

```
    $str = "Text";
    $wrap = "<span>|</span>";
    $text = "This is a really long Text where the word Text appears about 3 times Text";
    $temp = str_replace('|', $str, $wrap); // <span>Text</span>
    // find patern and 1-2 words before and after 
    // (to make it casesensitive, delete 'i' from patern)
    if(preg_match_all('/((\w+\s+){1,2}|^)text((\s+\w+){1,2}|$)/i', $text, $match)) {
      $res = array_map(function($x) use($str, $temp) { return '... '.str_replace($str, $temp, $x) . ' ...';}, $match[0]);
      echo implode(' ', $res);
}
```